# What's the right way to create a mosquitto subscription with a device and IoTAgent-UL

Tags: mqtt, fiware

I'm currently developing a Fiware based network, in which I have devices that report via HTTP and JSON over MQTT and work fine. The network has increased and now I need to attach some devices that use the UltraLight protocol. Doing so, I encountered some troubles.

I followed (to the best of my knowledge) the official documentation provided by the FIWARE Foundation in different sites (the official github repo, readthedocs, and so on). I tried installing the new agent on the same machine as the JSON agent, and it didn't work -more on that later-. In order to discard any conflicts, I used another VM in which -over Docker this time- I deployed a new instance of Orion CB, Mosquitto CB, mongo and the agent; a new complete stack of Fiware, basically.

After everything was deployed, I created a new service group on the agent via the rest API (POST /iot/devices), gave it an api key and the CB address. In this step I left the resource field empty, because I don´t really know what role does it play in the whole system. The response was 201, as expected.
The next step was to provision a device, which I did by POSTing to agent/iot/devices with the attributes I wanted, and the api key mentioned in last paragraph. Once again, the response was 201.

The problem arises when I try to publish a new measurement using mosquitto_pub. The command runs smoothly but the entity in Orion does not get updated. Accessing Orions DB (mongo) I can check that the entity was created successfully but it has an empty value. Moreover, checking the logs yields the following:

```
mosquitto    | 1559157902: New connection from 10.150.150.173 on port 1883.
mosquitto    | 1559157902: New client connected from 10.150.150.173 as mosqpub|28750-mqtt (p1, c1, k60).
fiware-iot-agent | time=2019-05-29T19:25:02.374Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=2c8aa6e3-faab-4166-9e20-0b362c165939 | trans=2c8aa6e3-faab-4166-9e20-0b362c165939 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.MongoDBGroupRegister arams ["resource","apikey"] with queryObj {"resource":"/iot/d","apikey":"apikeymia"} | comp=IoTAgent
fiware-iot-agent | time=2019-05-29T19:25:02.381Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=2c8aa6e3-faab-4166-9e20-0b362c165939 | trans=2c8aa6e3-faab-4166-9e20-0b362c165939 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.MongoDBGroupRegister elds [["resource","apikey"]] not found: [{"resource":"/iot/d","apikey":"apikeymia"}] | comp=IoTAgent
fiware-iot-agent | time=2019-05-29T19:25:02.382Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=2c8aa6e3-faab-4166-9e20-0b362c165939 | trans=2c8aa6e3-faab-4166-9e20-0b362c165939 | op=IOTAUL.Common.Binding | srv=n/a | essing device measures [/apikeymia/motion003/attrs] | comp=IoTAgent
mosquitto    | 1559157902: Client mosqpub|28750-mqtt disconnected.
```

after each try of publishing a new meassurment.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Indent text four spaces to format as code. I've submitted an edit.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In this step I left the resource field empty, because I don´t really know what role does it play in the whole system

Looking to the logs:

```
[...] queryObj {"resource":"/iot/d","apikey":"apikeymia"} | comp=IoTAgent
[...] not found: [{"resource":"/iot/d","apikey":"apikeymia"}] | comp=IoTAgent
```

I'd suggest using `"/iot/d"` instead of empty for the `resource` field. Maybe that could solve the problem.

Comment: I´ll give it a try. Thanks for the quick answer

Comment: Apparently, it worked just fine. I'll try and replicate this in the production environment. If it works, I'll mark the answer as correct.
Could you please explain what's the role of the resource? And whether I should use the default one every time?
Thank you in advance

Comment: It worked! Thank you! If you could answer my question on the last comment, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: The MQTT provisioning behaviour is linked to the following [issue](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-ul/issues/320) - at some point between releases, the required default switched between **blank** and **/iot/d**